# Shifting from lat long to NMEA packet

Tags: javascript, android

I am adding simple NMEA from lat long project, Lat long working perfectly but when shifting to nmea its giving me errors.

I will be greatful to you if anyone can help me out.

```
protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected Button retrieveLocationButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    retrieveLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieve_location_button);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,2000,0,this);
    locationManager.addNmeaListener(this);

    retrieveLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showCurrentLocation();
        }
    });     
}    



protected void showCurrentLocation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private class MyLocationListener implements NmeaListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        String message = String.copyValueOf(null);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,this);

        boolean isGood = locationManager.addNmeaListener((NmeaListener) this);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Provider status changed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: what errors? you need to give us an indication of how we can help

Comment: everytime I run the code after changing for nmea its forcely closed,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really give enough information about the 'errors' but it seems to me the following line will cause a compile time error...

```
locationManager.addNmeaListener(this);
```

Try changing it to...

```
locationManager.addNmeaListener(new MyLocationListener());
```

Comment: I have change the to below but same issue application forcely closed in starting
  LocationManager locationmanager;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.addNmeaListener(new NmeaListener(){
         public void onNmeaReceived(long timestamp, String nmea) {

                Log.d(TAG,"Nmea Received :");
                Log.d(TAG,"Timestamp is :" +timestamp+"   nmea is :"+nmea);


            }});